# Merging geometries in three.js

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js, geometry

I have a scene which contains multiple meshes, each of varying shapes and sizes.

I have looped through each Mesh and using **geometry.merge()** I have been able to create a new mesh from the geometries in the scene.

I want to mask the entire mesh with an alphaMask, however, each geometry has the material applied to it separately.

An example of this can be seen here - https://codepen.io/danlong/pen/KXOObr

```
    function addObjects(scene) {

    // merged geomoetry & material
    var mergedGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var mergedMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: "#444", transparent: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide, alphaTest: 0.5, opacity: 1, roughness: 1 });


    // multiple meshes
    var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(30, 5);
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: "#444" });

    var geo1 = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(30, 5);
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geo1, material );
    mesh1.position.x = 10;
    mesh1.position.y = 10;
    mesh1.position.z = 0;

    var geo2 = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(30, 5);
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geo2, material );
    mesh2.position.x = 20;
    mesh2.position.y = 20;
    mesh2.position.z = 0;

    var geo3 = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(30, 5);
    var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( geo3, material );
    mesh3.position.x = 30;
    mesh3.position.y = 30;
    mesh3.position.z = 0;

    // scene.add(mesh1, mesh2, mesh3);
    mesh1.updateMatrix();
    mergedGeometry.merge(mesh1.geometry, mesh1.matrix);

    mesh2.updateMatrix();
    mergedGeometry.merge(mesh2.geometry, mesh2.matrix);

    mesh3.updateMatrix();
    mergedGeometry.merge(mesh3.geometry, mesh3.matrix);

    // alpha texture 
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    var alphaMap = new THREE.Texture(image);
    image.onload = function()  {
        alphaMap.needsUpdate = true;
    };
    image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAAGUlEQVQoU2NkYGD4z4AHMP7//x+/gmFhAgCXphP14bko/wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
    mergedMaterial.alphaMap = alphaMap;
    mergedMaterial.alphaMap.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    mergedMaterial.alphaMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    mergedMaterial.alphaMap.repeat.y = 1;

    // merged geometry with alpha mask
    merge1 = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, mergedMaterial);
        merge1.rotation.z = -Math.PI/4;

    // merge geometry without alpha mask
    var merge2 = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, material);
    merge2.position.x = -100;
        merge2.rotation.z = -Math.PI/4;

    scene.add(merge1, merge2);
    return mesh;
}
```

The mesh on the left is the merged geometries which I want to apply the alphaMask to. The mesh on the right is the outcome of this and instead of the map being applied to the mesh as a whole, each of the geometries has the map applied.

Is there a way to mask the entire mesh and not each geometry?

--
three.js r86

**EDIT:**
I've tried to apply a clipping plane to my mesh but it's not the effect I'm looking for. I want to be able to apply an alphaMask across the whole mesh and reveal it however I make my mask image. Something like this effect - https://codepen.io/supah/pen/zwJxdb

Is it something to do with the UV's being preserved from the original geometries? Do I need to change these in some way?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve but one thing you should understand is that the texture coordinates to not change when merge the objects. If you want the effect to look more continuous you would need to manually adapt the uv coordinates after merging. Also merging geometries does not perform any boolean operations so the merged geometry will still contain the triangles inside the union of the objects.

Comment: Another idea would be to use clipping planes to achieve that 'cutting the whole object' effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Nicholas, essentially I want the texture to cover the entire merged mesh instead of what's happening in my example - where it looks as though each sphere has the texture applied to it. 
I like the look of the clipping planes, I might be able to achieve the effect I'm looking for with that technique instead. I'm not too sure how to adapt the uv co-ordinates after merging - the merged geometry I'm trying to apply this effect to is a lot more complex than 3 spheres.

Comment: I tried the clipping plane technique but it's not the effect that I'm after. Thanks for your suggestion. I may need to do something with the UV's as you mentioned?

Comment: Another idea would be to create a custom shader material where you vary the opacity not based on a texture but rather based on the position in model space. Basically in your fragment shader you could have something like: 
gl_FragColor.a = sin(vPosition.x); Try it yourself first, if you get stuck I can provide you with an example.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. I'll investigate that option and see where I get to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is an overlaid mask. This can be accomplished by rendering a single plane that has the alpha map applied, on top of the scene rendering. Using an orthographic camera, and controlling certain renderer settings, such as disabling automatic clearing of color.